# Knockout.Js selectedOptions filtered from options

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am binding a collection to a select multi, some of the items in the collection have the property "Selected": "True", i would like to set these as the selectedOptions in the select multi, figured i would use the ko.utils.arrayFilter to filter these out and then set them as the selectedOptions but for the life of me cant figure out the best way to do this.

Can enayone help, i have a Fiddler page set up that has everything but the  ko.utils.arrayFilter added here http://jsfiddle.net/dumbarse/TpnZh/3/.

```
<select data-bind="options:availableThings,optionsText: 'Title', selectedOptions: selectedThings" size="5"  multiple="true"></select>

Var initialThingsModel = [
            {"Id":1,"Title":"First","Selected":"True"},
            {"Id":2,"Title":"Next"},
            {"Id":3,"Title":"Another","Selected":"True"},
            {"Id":4,"Title":"Last"}
        ];

        var viewModel = {
            availableThings: ko.observableArray(initialThingsModel),
            selectedThings: ko.observableArray(),                
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ko.utils.arrayFilter` is the right method to use here (you can read more about it here: [Utility Functions in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)):

```
selectedThings: ko.utils.arrayFilter(initialThingsModel, 
    function(item) { return item.Selected == "True"; })
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CGK2A/)

If you want the `selectedThings` change when you add/remove items to `availableThings` you need to wrap the `ko.utils.arrayFilter` into a `ko.computed`:

```
var viewModel = {
     availableThings: ko.observableArray(initialThingsModel),               
};
viewModel.selectedThings = ko.computed(function() { 
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.availableThings(), 
       function(item) { return item.Selected == "True";}) 
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mJaAg/)